# How to handle internationalization in a Spring application (inside a class)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I already know how to handle internationalization in a Spring application using `<spring:message code="xxx"/>` in a JSP page. Now my users are allowed to change languages using simple links like

`<a href="?lang=it">IT</a>` and `<a href="?lang=en">EN</a>`

Now, I have to handle internationalization inside a class. This is what I did:

1) I created a text.xml file to identify where my texts are

```
.....
<bean id="messageSource"  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="struttura"></property>     
</bean>
......
```

2) I created a different properties files according to different languages

3) I use this method to get the message according to the locale

```
......
ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("text.xml");
String stringa = context.getMessage("textCode",null, locale);
.......
```

Everything works. But I'm sure this is not the fastest and cleanest way to do it. It looks too intricate!

Does anybody know a better way to reach my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MessageResource is a Spring managed bean so you can just inject it into your controllers (or other Spring managed classes):

```
@Autowired 
private MessageSource messageResource;
```

Comment: You should use the interface `MessageSource` instead of the concrete implementation `ResourceBundleMessageSource` for auto wiring. Also if you already have I18N you don't need another file containing another `MessageSource` just reuse the one already available.

Comment: Tx Deinum, did not have the code at hand so wasn't sure of the interface name; edited my answer.